# condition if is not getting executed --eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse

RowOneCollection is ArryList button has 2 buttons and all text name are "1"  namely btn1,btn2
RowTwoCollection is ArryList button has 2 buttons and all text name are "2" namely  btn3,btn4
RowThreeCollection is ArryList button has 2 buttons and all text name are "3" namely  btn5,btn6
RowFourCollection is ArryList button has 2 buttons and all text name are "4" namely  btn7,btn8
CheckBtnText is  =Null(Given as double quotation in pgm ) as string

I have set buttons to onclicklisteners when I click btn1  CheckBtnText gets assigned 
to 1 but in if condition it returns false. Plz help me out..

```
    for(int i=0;i<RowOneCollection.size();i++)
            {
                CheckBtnText=RowOneCollection.get(i).getText().toString();  
 returns false--->   if(CheckBtnText=="1")
                {
                    RowOneCollection.get(i).setEnabled(false);
                    RowTwoCollection.get(i).setEnabled(true);
                    RowThreeCollection.get(i).setEnabled(false);
                    RowFourCollection.get(i).setEnabled(false);     
                }
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You want to check for .equals() I think ;)

Comment: Use CheckBtnText.equals("1")

Answer (score 1):

Use CheckBtnText.equals("1") to compare values of strings otherwise you are checking if they are the same object.